# css position changing using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

In my html initially i am setting the data_focus class to display none. What I need, is on click of the right button i have to change the position of my data_focus class. I tried like this

Jquery:

```
var left=-8;
var top=10;
left=left+140;
$('.data_focus').css('{left:'+left+'}','{top:'+top+'}');
```

CSS:

```
.data_focus{
display:block; 
width:148px; 
height:148px; 
background:url(../images/focus_data.png) no-repeat; 
position:absolute; 
left:-8px; 
top:10px;}
}
```

but it is not changing the position. I dont know where i am going wrong.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you nee to use pass the styles as an object, not as a string

```
$('.data_focus').css({left:left,top:top});
```